# SSO doesn't login immediately

Tags: login, azure, microsoft-edge, single-sign-on

I created a web-app with SSO (Single-Sign-On) integrated. The app authenticates the user via AzureAD. What I want is, that the user is logged in immediately after clicking on the app-link.

Unfortunately, in some cases when I click on the link, the following window is shown, where I first have to select my account even though there is only one account.

[image]

My guess is that MS Edge (the browser I use) somehow thinks I have 2 accounts connected to my MS account but this is not the case.

I'm not really sure how to debug this issue or even how I should google it. My recent researches didn't get me any new ideas.

Therefore my question is, does somebody know how I can debug this issue or has a solution to it?